# Wrong save of a variable to .m file. How to reconstruct it?

Tags: matlab, file, struct

I had a struct array, and I wrongly saved it as .m file, instead of .mat. When I try to open it now, it opened in the editor with gibberish characters.

Anybody knows if there is a way to reconstruct my original struct?

Comment: Did you try renaming it, i.e. `filename.m -> filename.mat`

Comment: I use windows 10, didn't find a way to change the extension of the file. the usual "rename" option let me change only the name itself, not  the extension.

Comment: Control Panel -> Folder Options -> View -> uncheck Hide extensions for known file type

Comment: OR  inside matlab movefile('test.m','test.mat')

Comment: @Finn Great, thanks! I didn't think of the second option, works perfect.